# my test case error class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, boost

just I have the following errors coming when I compile the application I don't know my the comelier screen me like that I have create those method in my class and copy counstractur can someone help me?

```
Error   2   error C2062: type 'double' unexpected   
Error   7   error C2065: 'd' : undeclared identifier    
Error   1   error C2065: 'square_list' : undeclared identifier  
Error   8   error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union  
Error   4   error C2228: left of '.empty' must have class/struct/union  
Error   9   error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union    
Error   6   error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
```

test unit

> ```
> BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ut_ctor_default ) {
>   square_list<double> d;
>   BOOST_CHECK( d.empty() );
>   BOOST_CHECK( d.size() == 0 );
>   BOOST_CHECK( d.begin() == d.end() );
> }
> ```

my class

Comment: Check the case and name of your class. It doesn't match the class name used in the unit-test. Sqaure_List vs square_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named the class as `Sqaure_List` however in your test case you use name `square_list`

Comment: can you delete you Answer because i need to delete the questions?

Comment: @user3277743 I can not delete the answer because it is accepted. Nevertheless I think it is not very important to delete the question, is not it?